# strange copy values from one array to another

Tags: java

When I watched code examples in Java, I saw a strange code:

```
public class Application {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] x = {"A"};
          String[] y = x;
          x[0] = "B";
          System.out.print(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
     }
}
```

And I don't understand, why the result "B B" is correct? When I created and initialized an arrays x and y and assigned zero element of array x is equal to B, I think that an answer must be "B A".

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] y = x;
```

means that the array `y` now refers to the array `x`.

Consequently changing the contents of `x` means the contents of `y` change (since they're the same).

To elaborate, in Java, this:

```
String[] y = {...};
```

means that you're declaring `y` to be a *reference to an array*, not the array itself. So when you assign, you're assigning a reference and not copying the object values.

Comment: tell me please where I can read it in more detail ?

Comment: But, why this code :                                                        public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "A";
        String y = x;
        x = "B";
        System.out.print(x + " " + y);
    }
}  shows the correct result "B A"

Answer (score 2):

That's now how we copy arrays in Java. That's what you are doing now:

```
  x        y
+---+    +---+ 
| a |<---|-- |
+---+    +---+
```

So when you change the content of `x`, the content of `y` will be changed.

If you want to copy the array, you can use [`Arrays#copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28char%5B%5D,%20int%29):

```
String[] y = Arrays.copyOf(x, x.length);
```

Now, if you chagne `x`, `y` won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

In Java Array are considered as object reference. You are changing the value to the reference.

For illustrate try this one

```
   String[] x = {"A"};
   String[] y = x;    
   System.out.println(x==y);   //true -> X and Y are pointing the same reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

Java always does copy by value when an assignment operator is called. You declared yor first array like this:

String[] x = {"A"};

and x now holds reference to this array. When you assign x to y, it just copies reference to array x to y variable, so now both x and y represent the same array. When you change something in one array, the change affect other array too.
[Look here for better understanding](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/ArrayShallowCopy1.jpg)

Comment: This link does not redirect