# two of the same program produces different results

Tags: java

Yesterday I asked the a question about reference by value, [strange сopy values ​​from one array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19660848/1281433), and thought that I understood the answer after seeing this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] x = {"A"};
  String[] y = x;
  x[0] = "B";
  System.out.print(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
}
```

Then I saw this example which is identical to the first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String x = "A";
  String y = x;
  x = "B";
  System.out.print(x + " " + y);
}
```

And I do not understand why, in this example, the correct answer will be `B A`, instead of `B B`. I think, that I declare `x`, and then `y` refers to `x`.

Comment: `x[0] = "B"` modifies the existing object `x` by replacing the object at the index 0. `x = "B"` reassigns and therefor replaces `x`.

Comment: `String[]` and `String` are not identical in Java.

Answer (score 4):

First example:

You have declared a `String` array whose only member is `"A"`.  You declare another `String` array and assign it `x`.  Now you have two array references referring to the same array.  You change the contents to be `"B"`, so it's visible to both array references.  You modified the contents of the only array object present.

Second example:

You have declared a `String` whose contents is `"A"`.  You declare another `String` and assign it `x`.  Now you have two string references referring to the same `String`.  You change the variable `x` to be `"B"`, and now `x` and `y` are referring to different strings, so you see "B A".  You didn't change the original string object (`String`s are immutable).

Answer (score 1):

I think the key misunderstanding is revealed in:

> I think that I declare `x`, and then `y` refers to `x`.

Variables in Java hold *references* to *objects* (and primitives, but that's not really important here).  The only thing that can be referred to by a variable is an object.  Variables are not objects, and thus nothing can refer to them.  Let's consider the two code samples more closely.

In the first case, there are two variables and one array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] x = {"A"};
  String[] y = x;
  x[0] = "B";
  System.out.print(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
}
```

It may help to think in terms of what things are actually values, and what things are just references, or pointers, or handles (various) names, that refer to actual values. `x` and `y` are both variables and the *values* of these variables are references to objects (in this case, arrays of strings).  The particular value of `x`, in this case, is the same as the value of `y`, it's a reference to an array with one element, the String `"A"`.  The expression `x[0]` is evaluated by retrieving the array to which the variable `x` has a reference and taking its first element.  The expression `y[0]` is evaluated by retrieving the array to which the variable `y` has a reference and taking its first element.  Because `x` and `y` hold references to the *same* array, the first element of the array is the same as itself. The printed output is `B B`.

In the second case, there are two variables and no arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "A";
    String y = x;
    x = "B";
    System.out.print(x + " " + y);
}
```

The variable `x` holds a reference to a string, `"A"`.  The first assignment, `String y = x;` makes `y` hold a reference to the same string, `"A"`.  At this point, if you could modify anything about the string (but you can't in Java, because strings are immutable), you could do it using either `x` or `y`, and you'd see the result in either, because *both* variables have a reference to a *single* object.  However, the second assignment `x = "B";` makes the *value* of a `x` a reference to a different string, `"B"`.  It doesn't change the value of `y`, which is still a reference to the string `"A"`.  So, the expression `x` is evaluated and since `x` holds a reference to the string `"B"`, the result is `"B"`.  The expression `y` is evaluated, and since `y` holds a reference to the string `"A"`, the result is `"A"`.   The printed output is `B A`.

Perhaps the key point is that variables and objects are completely distinct. Objects exist, period.  Variables hold references to objects.  When you do something like

```
x.doSomething();
```

you're retrieving the value of `x`, which is an object, and then calling that object's `doSomething()` method.  You can retrieve the object to which a variable refers, and you can make a variable refer to a different object (through assignment).  Those are the *only* things you can do to an variable.  Anything else you can do, you're doing to an object.  This is particularly important in cases like:

```
  String[] x = {"A"}; ; there's an array {"Α"} and the variable `x` _refers_ to it
  String[] y = x;     ; retrieve the array to which `x` refers, and make `y` refer to it, too
  x[0] = "B";         ; retrieve the array to which `x` refers (and to which `y` also refers)
                      ; and make "B" its first element.

  String x = "A";     ; there's a string "A", and the variable `x` _refers to it
  String y = x;       ; retrieve the string to which `x` refers, and may `y` refer to it, too
  x = "B";            ; make `x` refer to the string "Β" (has no effect on what `y` refers to)
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` objects are immutable, this is why you are getting this behavior.

In your second example, you assign "A" to the variable `x`, then create variable `y`, which points to the same `String` in memory as varaible `x`. You then change your variable `x` to point to a new `String`. However, this doesn't affect the variable `y`; it still points to the initial `String`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second instance, you are setting a String to a value, which is treated as a primitive type in Java.  You are doing a one-time value assignment that stays permanent.

In the first instance, when you assign y to x, you are dealing with arrays.  Arrays are references to several values in memory, so when you say y = x, you are setting y so that it references the same values as x.  Thus, x and y are permanently equal to each other.

By this, x[0] and y[0] are pointing to the same exact value, and if you change one it is changed in both references.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the line

```
String[] y = x;
```

sets x to y.  **but** x refers to a memory address.

so when when you call

```
x[0] = "B";
```

you're changing the value at that address, which both `x` and `y` refer to.

---

In the second example, `x` and `y` aren't reference types.

so when you call

```
String y = x;
```

it takes the value at `x` and copies it to `y`, just like in the first example, but since `x` and `y` are **values** instead of **addresses**, than they're separate.

so when you call

```
x = "B"
```

It doesn't affect the value of `y` at all.  `y` remains `"A"`

<sub>*Technically `String`s are references too, it's just that they're immutable, and therefore behave similarly to value types like `int` and `float`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In

```
String[] x = {"A"};
```

you are creating reference `x` and assigning it to newly created array

```
x  ---> ["A"]
```

Next in

```
String[] y = x;
```

you are creating reference `y` and assigning it with *value of `x`* so it will be reference to same array that holds `x`

```
x  \
    }--->["A"]
y  /
```

NOT something like

```
y -> x ---> ["A"]
```

Now you have access to the **same array** via two references. It means that if you modify it via `x` you will be able to see this modifications via `y` because it is the same array, so

```
x[0] = "B";
```

will do

```
x  \
    }--->["B"]
y  /
```

and this is why result of `System.out.print(x[0] + " " + y[0]);` is `B B`

---

Now in your second example

```
String x = "A";
```

creates reference `x` and assigns it string `"A"`

```
String y = x;
```

creates another reference `y` and assigns it with same value of `x` so again they will use same object

```
x  \
    }---> "A"
y  /
```

but in

```
x = "B";
```

are are *not modifying same object* like in your first example, but *changing reference `x`* to hold different String `"B"` so now situation looks like

```
x  ---> "B"

y  ---> "A"
```

which is why `System.out.print(x + " " + y);` prints `B A`.